# Spring boot - multipart field serialization from snake case not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I have a Restful API and I want to upload a file and send other data at the same time. I use multipart-data because it seems more optimized than sending a base64.

But just like json I would like the parameters sent in my request to be in snake case. For now, I am obliged to send them in camel case as their definition in the class `MyCustomRequest`.

```
@PutMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> send(
    @PathVariable Integer id,
    @Valid MyCustomRequest request
) {
    //
}
```

For example if I send `custom_file`, it will not be deserialized correctly to `customFile`. And @JsonProperty does not work with multipart.

```
@Data
public class MyCustomRequest   {
    @JsonProperty('custom_file')
    @NotNull
    private MultipartFile customFile;

    @JsonProperty('time_saved')
    @Size(max = 1000)
    private String timeSaved;

    @Size(max = 1000)
    private String comment;
}
```

Any idea please? I want to respect the snake case everywhere to keep some consistency on the front-end and especially with Typescript typings.

Comment: Parameters are bound as is, so unless you replace that part of the data binding framework that is what it is. Rename the field and property to `custom_file` is the easiest and mimics your actual form as well.

Comment: Ok thanks it's clearer then, but in this case the solution may be to send a json next to the multipart, is it a good practice ?

Comment: What to send is a opinionated question/answer so I'm going to refrain from answering that.